# How to check if form is open, if open close form?

Tags: c#, winforms, form-control

How do I check if a form is open, and if it is open to close the form?

I tried the following, testing out some code but it keep saying the form is not open even when I know it is:

```
 foreach(Form a in Application.OpenForms) 
 {
     if (a is YouLikeHits_Settings) 
     {
         // About form is open
         MessageBox.Show("form open");
         break;
     }
     // About form is not open...
     MessageBox.Show("form not open");
     break;
 }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) contains opened forms. If form in this collection, then it is opened. Otherwise it is not opened (possibly closed).

```
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<YouLikeHits_Settings>().Any())
    MessageBox.Show("Form is opened");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Form is not opened");
```

Comment: Was I did was make a button which opens the form, then in another button I put in the code above, when I click it, it keeps saying, form is not open.

Comment: Your code worked to detect it being open :).

Any way after it pops up with the message box that the form is open I can close that certain form?

Comment: Yes, you can: `Application.OpenForms.OfType<YouLikeHits_Settings>().First().Close()`

Comment: i have tried it but my certainly form open cannot be closed automaticly

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i have same problem like this.. i tried your suggest code and it ran well when i show my form using `form1.show();` but when i tried use `form1.showdialog();`  the form cannot be closed. if any suggest for me i will say thanks so much

Comment: @aminvincent I think you should create new question with all related to your problem information and code to reproduce issue.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy thanks for your suggest,..finally i create new question and this the link that i created and that it solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471376/close-messagebox-when-incoming-new-message/35471810?noredirect=1#comment58640277_35471810

Comment: Many thanks, it worked like a charm and exactly what you said and I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work sure

```
            if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_YouLikeHits_Settings>().Any())
            {
                Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_YouLikeHits_Settings>().First().Close();
            }
            frm_YouLikeHits_Settings f1= new frm_YouLikeHits_Settings();
            f1.MdiParent = this;
            f1.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<talkForm>().Any())
    {
        talkForm frm = new talkForm();
        frm.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Form is opened");
    }
    else
    {
        talkForm frm = new talkForm();
        frm.Show();
        MessageBox.Show("Form is not opened");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```